# Prism modularity reload mechanism

Tags: silverlight, prism, modularity

I'm trying to implement modularity and have some complications. I implemented one module which called ModuleA which shows new childWindow in its initialize function;

```
public ModuleA()
{
   personViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
   detail = new ViewDetail(personViewModel);
}

public void Initialize()
{
   detail.Show();
}
```

My problem is that i can't show the view again because of missing opportunity of reload function. My module loaded on demand, i mean that i want to load module when user clicks button so, i do not have a chance to load module at the beginning and control its functions from its own events. then i tried to show view from my application like that;

```
private void ButtonModelA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.moduleManager.LoadModule(MyBootstrapper.ModuleAName);
   ChildWindow detail = new ModuleA.ViewDetail(new ModuleA.ViewModel.PersonViewModel());
   detail.Show();
}
```

in this way, loading module became unnecessary.

Is there a way to load module from out of it as on demand and show its view multiple times ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how this works in Silverlight, but I think there is a misunderstanding of Prism.

Prism is based on regions. That means that the applications user interface consists of ContentControls (or other region capable controls) that state to be a region. The region manager now adds all views that want to reside inside a specific region into exactly this region.

The modules just have to tell the region manager inside which region the views implemented in the specific module wants to reside:

```
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion( "RegionName", typeof( View ) );
```

If the specific region is currently not a part of the user interface, because the view that contains the control that hosts the region isn't part of the user interface itself, the view that wants to resied inside the region cannot be placed inside this region. The region manager just doesn't know of the region. To have the view shown you have to add the control that hosts the region to the user interface by hand.

Another way is to add a specific into a region by hand. Using this approach you don't have to register the view to the region manager. So when the region manager discovers the region it stays empty. Now you can add the view manually into the region using the region manager:

```
IRegion region = RegionManager.Regions["RegionName"];
region.Add( new View(), "ViewName" );
```

If you want to place views into a region depending on any state or user action you have to add the into the region by hand. Have a look at the Stock Trader Reference Inplementation. It explains in a very simple manner how to add views to regions triggered by user action.

Comment: I understand what you mean also i have checked out stock trader implementation. But, in this implementation modules loaded as whenavailable and one of view of module's registered to main view. even i use region, I need to entranceway to register my view which included in module beside initialize method because this method called once.

Comment: In my scenario, i have buttons at the top of main view and these buttons are not part of modules. When i click button, i want to load module and show view. Until here there is no problem. But, when i click button again i can't show my view again because initialize method called once. I need that load modules on demand and reach its inside many times.

Comment: You do not have to initialize your modules more than once because they are already initialized. You just have to add your view multiple times into a region.

Comment: Yeah, i know they are already initialized. I want to add my view into a region from outside of module. For example, by instance of module which is initialized already but how ?

Comment: With the code above. This code has to be called from inside the module. To get the request into the module you can use the EventAggregator, for example.

Comment: i can also use reguestnavigate function of regionmanager but i do not want to refer my module anywhere

Comment: according to state i m gonna implement my custom module manager to solve it.